# Replacing a line by a cylinder

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

How can I replace the line in the following graph by a tiny cylinder?

> parametricPlot3D[ {CosSqrt[2]t, Sin[Sqrt[2]t](3+ Cos[t]), Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 100}]

Comment: `ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[Sqrt[2] t], Sin[Sqrt[2] t] (3 + Cos[t]), 
  Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness@6]` ?

Comment: That doesn't work for some reason!

Comment: So instead of [t] I need something like {Cos[t],Sin[t],s}. Can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can post-process the output of `ParametricPlot3D` to change `Line`s into `Tube`s:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[Sqrt[2] t], Sin[Sqrt[2] t] (3 + Cos[t]), Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 100}] /. 
 Line -> (Tube[#, .05] &)
```

[image]

To get a hollow tube use `CapForm[None]` and use two different colors for inside and outside faces (say, `FaceForm[Blue, Yellow]`):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[Sqrt[2] t], Sin[Sqrt[2] t] (3 + Cos[t]), Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 12}] /. 
  Line ->  ({CapForm[None], FaceForm[Blue, Yellow], Tube[#, .25]} &)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I have this Tube open from the edge? So it looks like a cylinder (empty from inside)

Comment: Is there any solution to get a  hollow cylinder ? Thanks again!

Comment: @AbdelRahman, please see the update.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed!

Comment: @AbdelRahman, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se and thank you for the accept.

Comment: I actually still have a naïve question, sorry! But, I would like to animate this tube. Can you help me in that? You helped me too much today!

Comment: @AbdelRahman, Try `Animate[ParametricPlot3D[{ Cos[Sqrt[2] t], 
    Sin[Sqrt[2] t] (3 + Cos[t]), Sin[t ]}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1],  
   PlotRange -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {-1.1, 1.1}}] /. 
  Line -> ({CapForm[None], FaceForm[Opacity[.5, Blue], Yellow], 
      Tube[#, .1]} &), {tmax, 1, 50, .01}]`. If you post it as a new question with additional details  you  will probably get better suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, I will ask a new question about the animation in general :)